# Hibernate Automatic Versioning

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have developed a customer maintenance application. Users can alter the customer details via web interface. I want to handle the following scenario:

1. `User 1` loads `customer1` details.
2. `User 2` loads `customer1` details.
3. `User 1` changes and saves `customer1`'s `name`.
4. `User 2` only changes and saves `customer1`'s age.

In the scenario above, finally database holds `customer1`'s old name and the new age because `User 2` overwrites `User 1`'s update. I'm using Hibernate. I had heard that Hibernate Automatic Versioning supports this. If any one know  how to handle this please advise me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You just need to add a field annotated with `@Version`:

```
public class Customer {

 @Id
 private Long id;

 @Version
 private Long version;

 // rest of the fields, etc.

}
```

Read [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/jpa-20-concurrency-and-locking) article for more information.

Comment: I use SpringJDBC over any ORM in my Java Project. But I need to add some Hibernate's @Version functionality, to prevent some situation like discribed there. So maybe you can suggest me JDBC realization?

Comment: The general term for this approach is called _optimistic locking_. You can find some guidance here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8880896/309683

Answer (score 0):

one solution, when second request tends to update details first check if it is updated after details loaded, if so then raise exception and allow user to change after loading details again, you can use modification time stamp to compare