# How to prevent two users to edit one row from DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, zk

i am using Spring/Hibernate/ZK. In one tab i get object from DB for editing  by user, but second user can open the same tab and the same object for editing . I want to informed second user whit message like "This object is аlready open" and hide buttons for save.Тhus second user can see current data from DB to this object but can`t edint him.Is there a way to check session  for this object or another way to do that.

Comment: There are multiple ways. Add status column to Db with values EDIT for edited ones. Keep a reference on JVM (in context or in session). The main question is how to "release" the objects?

Comment: Yes the problem is how to "release" the objects . Every way I think I get to this dead end.

Comment: How about `editing_start_date` + `editor_id` field? If it's null or editing started e.g. 10 minutes ago another user can also start editing. For the first user we can show a warning that editing must be completed in 10 minutes (or create AJAX call by 1 minute timer refreshing the `editing_start_date`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers mostly look at the database, but if all users use the same zk application to access the database, you could keep track of opened objects in the `Composer` or `ViewModel` (depending whether you use MVC or MVVM; I'll just call it controller).

Your controller would need a `static` list of objects that are currently modified. If a user requests to open an object that is not in the list, everything is fine and your controller enables the fields and save button. Otherwise, those are disabled and/or you display a message.

The tricky part is clearing objects from that list. If a user presses the save button, you just remove the object from the list. But what if the user doesn't and just closes the tab or their session just times out? In this case you need a callback, or a mechanism that regularly checks whether the screen is still open.

You could achieve this by adding a zk timer to the tab that pings every now and then and updates the timestamp in your static list (so make it a map). If a new user tries to edit the object, check how old the last timestamp is. If it is old enough (i.e. the previous user saved it or abandoned the screen), allow them to edit it.

Still, you have to think about what to do if a user just keeps the screen open. How long are they allowed to keep the lock on the object? This is an issue in Microsoft Office as well. If multiple users try to open an Excel file from a network location, the first one gets to lock and the others cannot save until that user saves.

Answer (score 1):

- You may have additional field which indicates that column is being edited. When first user starts work, the field would be updated. The second user would query object with 'on hold' status and your code would handle this.
- Other way - use [Hibernate `@Version`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html) field in your entity. It holds object version which is incremented after every update operation. If second user would save object after first one already saved, it would throw `OptimisticLockException` which you could handle in your code. More about optimistic and pesimistic locking: [Chapter 5. Locking](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/devguide/en-US/html/ch05.html). Related discussions: [Hibernate Automatic Versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631280/hibernate-automatic-versioning) and [When to use @Version and @Audited in Hibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374604/when-to-use-version-and-audited-in-hibernate)

Comment: Hibernate @Version  will throw OptimisticLockException on save . I don`t want user to do some work and when hit save to get massage . For the other method if first user open the tab and after this he just  close the window or close browser  the field which traces for edited object  It will not be update.

Comment: You may use Javascript to detect page close and then execute a method which would update status field. Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443503/run-javascript-code-on-window-close-or-page-refresh or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746851/execute-javascript-function-before-browser-reloads-closes-browser-exits-page

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use Optimistic Concurrency Control with Versioning and when Hibernate throws Concurrency Update issue due to same row is being updated in two transaction then use one of below strategy

- First Wins Strategy
- Last Wins Strategy
- Merge Conflicting Update Strategy

First Wins Strategy is not good solution as it leads to lost update and user will get frustrated that all his work is lost.

By Last Wins Strategy one of user will get error message that you are working on Stale data and  start your transaction again . By this way also user can get frustrated due to fact that now again he need to restart operation from beginning but his changes will not lost.

Instead go with Merge conflicting Update Strategy, when Hibernate throws Stale object exception reload screen with new data and user will see updated result and allow him to proceed with latest data. In this user changes will not loss and user will not get error message , just his screen reloads with fresh data and he can decide whether to proceed or not .

You can take example any e-commerce site and you will get one of result of either Last Wins Strategy or Merge Conflicting Update Strategy. Two user can start to by one item but one of user will get message in last screen that item is not stock.